# How to bring project into compliance with composer.json?

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php, del

That must be what `composer install` is supposed to do. But it doesn't remove no longer needed packages. Well, I can remove packages with `composer remove PACKAGE` instead of editing `composer.json` by hand, but that still leaves dependencies in `composer.lock` and `vendor` dir.

Answer (score 0):

If `composer remove PACKAGE` does not work, probably the package that you don't require *is required* by another package.

if you want to make sure, delete vendor folder and do a composer update (beware of the `vendor/package: *` that you have on your  `composer.json`)

If the vendor still have that package, it's because it's needed by another.